# Searching in SQL Server with C#. There are many textbox and many probability

Tags: c#, sql, database

[Search Form][image: 1]

I will do a search in the database, if there are sections that are empty, should I type a query one by one? If all the pieces are filled in, my code will be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Thesis AS T
INNER JOIN Person AS A ON A.PersonID = T.AuthorID 
                       AND A.PersonFullName = 'Author name'
INNER JOIN Person AS S ON S.PersonID = T.SupervisorID 
                       AND S.PersonFullName = 'supervisor'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person AS CS ON CS.PersonID = T.SupervisorID 
                             AND CS.PersonFullName = 'cosupervisor'
INNER JOIN Enstitute AS E ON E.EnstituteID = T.EnstituteID 
                          AND E.EnstituteName = ' enstitutename '
INNER JOIN University AS U ON U.UniversityID = E.UniversityID 
                           AND U.UniversityName='universityname '
WHERE 
    Title = 'title' AND 
    ThesisNo = 123 AND 
    [Type] = 'type' AND
    [Language] = ' Language' AND
    [SubmitDate] BETWEEN 2000 AND 2021
```

Comment: That is entirely up to you. If your query requires all of the inputs in order to produce the correct results, then you need to do proper validation and ensure that the user is populating all fields.

Comment: user not have to populating all fields . @greenjaed

Comment: Then, check for input and then use [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0) to build your query according to what they entered.

Comment: Also, regardless of what you do, make sure to [Parameterize your query](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx)

Comment: See @AaronBertrand on [#BackToBasics: An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this (I don't know what DB are you using, this is just an algoritm):

```
-- Input parameters:

 @Author VARCHAR(50);   
 @Supervisor VARCHAR(50);  
 @Enstitute VARCHAR(50);   
 @University VARCHAR(50);

------
SELECT * 
FROM Thesis AS T
INNER JOIN Person AS A ON A.PersonID = T.AuthorID 
                    
INNER JOIN Person AS S ON S.PersonID = T.SupervisorID 
                     
LEFT OUTER JOIN Person AS CS ON CS.PersonID = T.SupervisorID 
                           
INNER JOIN Enstitute AS E ON E.EnstituteID = T.EnstituteID 
                        
INNER JOIN University AS U ON U.UniversityID = E.UniversityID 
    
WHERE 
    (@Author is null or A.PersonFullName = @Author
   AND 
 ( @SuperVisor is null or  S.PersonFullName = @Supervisor)
  AND 
    (@Enstitute is null or   E.EnstituteName = @Enstitute
 AND 
    (@University is null or  U.UniversityName=@University)
  And

  Title = 'title' AND 
    ThesisNo = 123 AND 
    [Type] = 'type' AND
    [Language] = ' Language' AND
    [SubmitDate] BETWEEN 2000 AND 2021
```